# Fix broken /lib/modules/ and apt

Tags: boot, apt, updates, disk

I have a machine that went neglected for some time, and ended up with a full disk and full boot partition ..  At that point any `apt` command would not work, because no space.

Before we start, this server runs a minimal MySQL DB  -- and `/var/log/` was at `14MB` and `/var/mail/` was at `18kb`.  I also tried to run `apt clean` and `apt autoclean` -- Disk was still full ..  After Googling and Googling .. And EVERY post saying just run `apt clean` (of course) I decided to attempt to take matters into my own hand and I FAFO.

So I ran `uname -r` and it cam out

```
4.4.0-119-generic
```

So I went into the boot drive and removed anything not `4.4.0-119-generic`.  This has always been what I would try in the past and it usually clears up enough for me to run a `apt install -f` and `apt autoremove` then `update-grub` -- Usually all is gtg after that.

My issue is that there was not enough space on the hard disk to run any `apt install` or `apt autoremove` -- So I did the same in `/usr/src/` and in `lib/modules/`

**RECAP** I cleared the `usr/src` and `lib/modules` of "unused" kernels.

I believe this is where I messed up.  Now when I try to run `apt install -f` I get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 158 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up linux-image-4.4.0-208-generic (4.4.0-208.240) ...
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-208-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-208-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.4.0-208-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I see the source of the error *(which alerted me to my mistake)*

```
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-208-generic: No such file or directory
```

I tried to run `sudo apt --fix-broken install` as well -- Same error -- No avail.

What can I do to fix this seemingly monstrous conundrum I have cornered myself into?

Comment: Are you sure this is not a Disk Space issue ?

Comment: I cleared up the disk space by deleting all the things mentioned .. When I run a `df` the drive is showing `74%` and boot is showing `14%`  --  Did my question not make sense?  I cleared out the `modules` and `src` directories to gain space.

Comment: 20.04 was released with the 5.4 kernel so I'm not really sure what kind of system you're working with. You sure this isn't 16.04 with that kernel?

Comment: You are correct .. I am sorry ..  This server is still running 16.04 -- Would doing a dist upgrade fix it?

Comment: Give the package manager what it wants for the purges: If it complains about a missing file, use touch and create the file, make missing direcctories.  Package manager is too stupid to realize missing files should be OK when you're trying to remove them anyway, but it really doesn't care if they are empty substitutes.

Comment: @ubfan1 -- Can you please make this an answer ..  I know it's a trivial thing I should have *tried*  .. But if someone runs across this ever again ..  It'll help them understand that `autoremove` is indiscriminate and will work just by replacing with empty files and directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the package manager what it wants for the purges: If it complains about a missing file, use touch and create the file, make missing directories. Package manager is too stupid to realize missing files should be OK when you're trying to remove them anyway, but it really doesn't care if they are empty substitutes.

Comment: Who downvotes a question, and the answer, but gives no feedback?  Sorry .. That wasn't me.